# Externalizing the location of logback.xml in Spring Boot using application.properties

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, logback

How can I customize the location of logback.xml in Spring Boot using application.properties?

I tried below but is not working.

application.properties

```
logging.config = /home/dev-01/Documents/logback.xml
```

It is working if the logback.xml is located in the resource folder, but not working if it is located outside the project.

It is also working if the I supply as an environment variable like

```
-Dlogging.config=/home/dev-01/Documents/logback.xml
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Below construct worked for me (but I used relative path instead of absolute):

```
logging.config=file:/home/dev-01/Documents/logback.xml
```

Comment: This does not work with application.properties loaded programmatically using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Can I configure the app so it can read from external logback.xml without the application.properties?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to pass it as a program argument --loggind.config it is written somewhere in the spring doc that some props are loaded very early on runtime