# Externalize logback.xml in Spring MVC

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, logback, slf4j

I use SL4J for logging in my Java Spring MVC Web Application. I have the `logback.xml` file under `/src/main/resources`. In my `pom.xml` file, I have the following related to logging:

```
<properties>
<org.slf4j-version>1.6.4</org.slf4j-version>
<logback.version>1.0.1</logback.version>
</properties>
```

And the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logback -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now logging is working fine for me. But now I am trying to move the `logback.xml` file outside the war file so that I do not have to change the war file to change the logging level. I was trying to move the file to `${catalina.base}/conf/`. I was unable to find a way to specify the path of the file which would be ${catalina.base}/conf/logback.xml. I have found a couple of similar questions, but I couldint find a solution that I could use:
[Externalized the location of logback.xml in Spring Boot using application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944356/externalized-the-location-of-logback-xml-in-spring-boot-using-application-proper) and 
[logback externalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288623/logback-externalization). Is there any way I can move the file under the conf folder under tomcat and specify its path so that I can keep this `logback.xml` ouside the war file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not good idea to put logging properties in tomcat config folder. Better to put it inside application folder/war.**

But there is a way to locate `logback.xml` from external directory by setting a property in your spring application properties file.

For example in `application.properties` add
`logging.config=file:/home/user/tomcat/conf/logback.xml`

Comment: I +1d your answer, but I'm curious about the bold statement. Can you justify why it's not a good idea? It seems to me that I might want to change my log-level without having to redeploy the application war - which suggests I'd be better off with the log configuration in tomcat/conf

Comment: Your war file will be extracted once you run tomcat then you can access that file whenever needed. The main reason is config of tomcat folder is for tomcat configurations, not for our application. And sometimes anyone can be confused about that file if you put it in tomcat config folder!